# get a key-value pair from an object to a new object jq

Tags: json, jq, key-value

I get this object

```json
{
  "138.68.226.120:26969": 1,
  "178.128.50.37:26969": 1,
  "207.180.218.133:26969": 1,
  "66.42.67.157:26969": 1,
  "140.82.14.193:26969": 1,
  "51.15.39.62:26969": 1,
  "144.217.91.232:26969": 1,
  "144.217.81.95:26969": 1,
  "68.183.105.143:26969": 1,
  "192.99.246.177:26969": 1,
  "167.99.98.151:26969": 1,
  "59.79.71.205:26969": 1
}
```

When I use jq '."59.79.71.205:26969"' it give me the value only, is there a way to get the key-value from the object into an object like the example

```
{
 "59.79.71.205:26969": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the Object Construction section of the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#TypesandValues).

```
jq '{"59.79.71.205:26969"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const splittedObject = Object.keys( // get all the keys
    yourObject
).map((key) => { // then for each key, turn the key into an object with the key-value pair
    return {
        [key]: yourObject[key] // assign the value to the key and voila
    }
});
```

Now `splittedObject` is an array of those objects with one key, it's better to demonstrate with this snippet:

```js
const yourObject = { "138.68.226.120:26969": 1, "178.128.50.37:26969": 1, "207.180.218.133:26969": 1, "66.42.67.157:26969": 1, "140.82.14.193:26969": 1, "51.15.39.62:26969": 1, "144.217.91.232:26969": 1, "144.217.81.95:26969": 1, "68.183.105.143:26969": 1, "192.99.246.177:26969": 1, "167.99.98.151:26969": 1, "59.79.71.205:26969": 1 };

const splittedObject = Object.keys( // get all the keys
    yourObject
).map((key) => { // then for each key, turn the key into an object with the key-value pair
    return {
        [key]: yourObject[key] // assign the value to the key and voila
    }
});

console.log(splittedObject);
```

By the way, can I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: i wanted to make it in a small script using jq that was the problem, when i tried using jq in a bash script